# Add document link to list item from a SharePoint workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, url, updatelistitems, update

I have a list workflow that creates a new document in a different library. This list has a column that will be used to save a URL with a link to the new document that will be created within the workflow. Is it possible to populate this value within the workflow?

At the moment this is done manually, so the user starts the workflow within the list, a new document is created inside a library, then the user navigates to that library and copies the link, navigates back to the original list and paste the link in the relevant column and also types a description. I would like to do this inside the workflow. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible

Find the workflow steps below

[image: Full workflow]

[image: Step to create document]

[image: Step to get document url]

[image: Step to assign URL in current list item]

Comment: Fantastic Monica! thanks heaps! it worked like a charm. A further improvement could be to change the text that says "type the description" which can be a short word like "DOC" instead of the very long web address. this because this link appear on the list and make the column vey wide. since it adjusts the width of the column to accommodate the length of the link. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Rightly said. Here i have taken the url in single line of text field. But the best option could be to create hyperlink / url field, assign the value from SD workflow as "url, link title". Space between "comma" and "link title" is mandatory. This way you can have shorter column width and better user experience.